# How to reject user inputted pathes if outside of a certain directory in C

Tags: c, file, user-permissions, chroot

Ok so I have this C program that takes, as user input, a path to a file. I want to be able to open that file, but *only* if it's in another path. For example, I have this directory structure:

```
├── forbidden-file
└── directory1
    ├── permitted-file1
    └── directory2
        └── permitted-file2
```

and I want to reject any paths that point to outside of `directory1`, relative to `directory1`. So stuff like `../forbidden-file` and `directory2/../../forbidden-file` would be rejected, but stuff like `permitted-file1`, `directory2/../permitted-file1`, and `directory2/permitted-file2` would be allowed.

I've looked into `chroot` a bit, but that doesn't really suit my needs because I need to only reject the paths inputted by the user while leaving my program free to access any files outside of `directory1` in my example.

I'm kinda stumped at the minute, so any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks for your time and have a nice day.

Comment: Use [realpath](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/realpath.3.html) to get the canonical absolute path and check whether it has the `forbidden-file` path as a prefix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One proven way of handling such scenarios are through keeping a **White List** for allowed paths or **Black List** for not allowed paths. here is a simple hello world on white list as well as black list implementation for your reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <libgen.h>
#define ENTRIES (3)

const char *white_list[ENTRIES]={
    "/home/allowed_dir1",
    "/home/allowed_dir2",
    "/home/allowed_dir3"
};

const char *black_list[ENTRIES]={
    "/home/blocked_dir1",
    "/home/blocked_dir2",
    "/home/blocked_dir3"
};

int check_white_list(char *dirname){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<ENTRIES;i++){
        if(strcmp(dirname, white_list[i])==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int check_black_list(char *dirname){
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<ENTRIES;i++){
        if(strcmp(dirname, black_list[i])==0){
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;    
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;


    char allowed_file[30] = "/home/allowed_dir0/myfile"; //change paths here for sample
    //get dir name of myfile
    char *dir_name = dirname(allowed_file);

    /*
     * white list method
     */    
    if(check_white_list(dir_name)==0){
        printf("match found in white list\n");
    }else{
        printf("match not found in white list\n");
    }

    /*
     * black list method
     */    
    if(check_black_list(dir_name)==0){
        printf("march found in black list\n");
    }else{
        printf("match not found in black list\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```